# What are the pros and cons of building a shed on stilts on ground that is quite boggy for a month or two in the winter?

Tags: shed

The stilts would be wooden and with concrete foundations. The shed would have a plank floor maybe 30cm above the ground, and there is sufficient wind to keep it dry. The area gets little snow.

Comment: Your basically building a wooden deck and putting a shed on it then, correct?  What floor load is required?  What will the contents be?

Comment: I had a shed like that for a long time. The main issue is that leaves and debris will blow under eventually, so be sure you can clean it out. Animals might like to live under there also. I would lay down gravel before building the shed. It is best if the area stays dry and clean. Our shed was compromised when a building inspector said we had to use more beams at the outside edges (lowering the ground clearance of two sides) so we effectively had a box that was difficult to access. Stupid. We were not going to park a car in there, so it didn't need the extra support.

Comment: The shed can't be simply put on a deck, because of the strong winds. I'll have to bolt uprights, either timber or angle iron, to the piers. The contents will be gardening equipment mainly, and some building materials - a couple of hundred kilograms maximum, spread over an area of something like 8m^2. It will be on moorland - part of my garden is moorland, and few trees grow around here - so I'll have no big worries about leaves or debris. No building inspection required either. I was thinking of laying a plastic sheet with some stones on top from elsewhere in the garden.

Comment: If you need to be above the winter waterline, you may be able to get some old telephone poles and put them into the base with cement or packed rock. Then make a frame work above the high water mark or level I made a 2 level play house when my kids were young now grand kids play in the upper level and the lawn tractor is on the lower level, this was under ,120 square feet and did not require a permit in my area.